# Why text is displaying as box instead of in its original language Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, fonts, qt-creator, qt5

I am reading file as following:

```
#include "databasemanager.h"

#include<QDebug>
#include<QMessageBox>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include<QFile>

DatabaseManager::DatabaseManager()
{
    QFile file("words.csv");
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text ))
     {
      QTextStream in(&file);
      in.setCodec("UTF-8");

      while(!in.atEnd())
          {
              QString line = in.readLine();
              vals.append(line);
          }

     }else{
        qDebug() << "Could not open";
     }

}

DatabaseManager* DatabaseManager::instance = 0;

DatabaseManager* DatabaseManager::Instance(){
    return instance;
}

QStringList DatabaseManager::getGujaratiMap(){
    return vals;
}
```

And using the read text as following:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include<QTextCodec>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    DatabaseManager *dm = new DatabaseManager();
    QStringList val = dm->getGujaratiMap();

    ui->textBrowser->setText(val.at(100));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

The file is being correctly viewed in my gedit text viewer, so there is no issue with file. When I am reading the file and printing the content on my terminal using c++ code, it prints correctly. My terminal has default font  "Monospace", I set the same font for my textBrowser as:

```
<widget class="QTextBrowser" name="textBrowser">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>70</x>
      <y>30</y>
      <width>256</width>
      <height>192</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Monospace</family>
     </font>
    </property>
   </widget>
```

Still the output is:

[image: The text in Gujarati is being displayed as box]

I tried many different fonts (available in ui editor) but the text remains in the form of boxes. One more thing, when I copy text from QTextBrowser and paste it in terminal or any text editor it displays correctly. What modification in code will fix it ?

Comment: It seems like coding problem. Are you sure that `words.csv` uses UTF-8?

Comment: @sukhoi191 Yes, because I am exporting my mysql data into csv, from phpmyadmin selecting utf-8 as encoding scheme. Also when I am copying text from textBrowser shown in question and pasting it on any editor it displays correctly i.e. in gujarati.

Comment: Ok, and what's the expected value to be shown inside `QTextBrowser` in that case?

Comment: "109 Adar s અદાર માતાનો;"  This is what I want the content of QTextBrowser to look like. I have copied this sentence from QTextBrowser only.

Comment: If text is actually correct (as proven by copy-paste *from* `QTextBrowser`), then this is a font-related problem. Also boxes are typically shown when some glyph is not available. Try changing font or font options.